# CD Accidentally formatter, can I recover data

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery

I accidentally formatted an old CD but wanted to check if there's a way to recover some of the data since i haven't written anything on it.

I'm currently using Ubuntu 18.04 and have tried with using programs such as Dvddisaster and foremost but no luck since I'm a newbie in this.

The CD is a music CD-ROM from 2005 so I'm not if there's a way of getting the data back but I appreciate any tips.

Best,

Comment: Well it certainly wasn’t a CD *ROM*. What exactly did you do?

Comment: Whoops you are right. I ran it on Windows with an external CD drive and it gave me the option of reading it as a CD or as a USB. I clicked on 'Read as a CD' and it automatically started formatting it. Then I ran It on my Ubuntu machine and it was blank.

Comment: I've been reading the article on this link but not really sure where to begin: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: Probably have to buy specialized software since the format destroyed the table of contents. You can try a free evaluation to see if it works.....http://www.infinadyne.com/cddvd_diagnostic.html

Comment: Before you try the data recovery root, what media was it, and was the content unique? Do you know what format the data was in?

Comment: @davidgo It was audio files. Not really sure about the format but they maybe mp3.

Comment: If they were MP3 files that you cant get.from elsewhere, use ddrescue to bit copy the disk to a file, then use photorec to see if you can recover them.

Comment: How long did this “formatting” process take? Also, if Windows asked to format right away, the data may already have been deleted.

Comment: @DanielB The formatting lasted at most 2 to 3 seconds since I ejected the CD as soon as I realized it was being formatted